# Filter Search in Datagridview using textbox

Tags: vb.net-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a `searchbox` as shown in the image below. I want that when i type a letter or a number, the data `gridview` will display the data that matches to what I've inputted in the `searchbox`. I have already a code for that but it is only for one column and it only works at first but when I add other data, it is not working at all. Can you please suggest a better code for that? Thank you! :)

Btw, here's my code for the filter:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
            EmployeeProfileBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Employee_Lname] Like '{0}%'",
  Me.txtSearch.Text.Trim())

        End Sub
```

[image]

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUuXT.png)

Comment: What is `EmployeeProfileBindingSource`? Is it the `DataSource` of the `Datagridview`?

Comment: See my answer, hope it will help :)

Comment: Yes it is the source of Datagridview :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should get rid of the error when you try to search with another keyword, here I filled the `Employee_ID` and the `Employee_Fname` columns, just to show you how it works :

```
Public Class Form1
    Private dtTableGrd As DataTable
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = EmployeeProfileBindingSource 
        dtTableGrd = EmployeeProfileBindingSource
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        dtTableGrd.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Employee_Fname Like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now if you need to search in more columns, just copy and paste the filtering code above and change the name of the column.

**Finally, I hope that will help you, please let me know if it does :)**

Comment: I'm sorry but I think there's a syntax error in the code above?

dtTable.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Employee_ID", .AutoIncrement = True, .AutoIncrementSeed = 1, .AutoIncrementStep = 1},
                              New DataColumn("Employee_Fname")},
                              New DataColumn("Employee_Lname")})

it says that there are "Too many arguments to 'Public  Sub addRange(..."

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer , Yes, sorry it's my fault, but try it now i fixed it, i removed the `}` after `("Employee_Fname")`, and i also changed this line : `dtTableGrd.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Employee_Fname Like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"`, i edited my answer.

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer .  You can see it here too > [Clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vh80dj6pozozy2t/Clip_2.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer , Any uptates about the error?

Comment: Sorry, late update. Ahm, Am I really going to type all of those "Dims" above? If so? What if I have thousands of records to save? I mean do i have to keep on putting those "Dim dr as DataRow..."?

Comment: I've seen the clip. It was perfectly the output that I want but I need to know how can I produce an output like yours in a dynamic manner :). Anyways! Thank you for responding to my question, you're a great help to my project. I'll wait for your update.

Comment: Yes, i made that just to show you how, but you can change the code to fill your needs, you have a `DataSource` called `EmployeeProfileBindingSource` right? So just replace `dtTable` with your `DataSource` in the lines where it syas `DataGridView1.DataSource = dtTable` and `dtTableGrd = dtTable` and then delete all the `Dims` above.Do you want me to update the answer to show what i was saying??

Comment: Please do. :) Thank you!

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer , Okay i edited my answer hope it'll help.

Comment: There's still an error on the syntax. On the part 
dtTableGrd = EmployeeProfileBindingSource, it says that the Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' cannot be converted to System.Data.DataTable..

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer ,  Oh, this is not gonna work if it is `BindingSource`, try this : `dtTableGrd = DataGridView1.DataSource` instead of `dtTableGrd = EmployeeProfileBindingSource`.

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer , Sorry, i'm not able to help you with that, because i don't have any connection for any database, so i don't know what's happening in your project, but i think this solution will not work with you.

Comment: It's okay. I already have an answer. But the method I use only display the Fname or Lname. But its okay, it could be an alternative. Hahah! Anyways, thank you very much for your help! Godbless.